# How to create custom select with vanillaJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to do a navbar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50R6f.png) with VanillaJS.

The style and project is set but I cannot make the dropdown keep open when moving the mouse on inner elements. After moving outside the button it closes.

This is the desired result: [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGQWa.gif)

```js
const categoriesLink = document.querySelector('.categories__link');
const categoriesList = document.querySelector('.categories__wrapper');

function categoriesVisible() {
    categoriesList.style.display = 'block';
}

function categoriesHidden() {
    categoriesList.style.display = 'none';
}

categoriesLink.addEventListener('mouseover', categoriesVisible);
categoriesLink.addEventListener('mouseout', categoriesHidden);
```

```css
.header__nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
}

.categories__link {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.categories__link:hover {
    color: #2F80ED;
}

.categories__wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: -100px;
}

.categories__content {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.categories__content::after {
    z-index: -10;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #BDBDBD;
}

.categories__content::before {
    z-index: 10;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.categories__list {
    display: flex;
    padding: 14px 30px;
}

.list__link {
    line-height: 150%;
    color: #000000;
}

.list__link:hover {
    color: #2F80ED;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__nav">
  <nav class="nav">
    <span class="categories__link">Categories</span>
    <div class="categories__wrapper">
      <div class="categories__content">
        <div class="categories__list">
          <ul class="left__list">
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Sport</a></li>
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>World</a></li>
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Covid</a></li>
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Business</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="right__list">
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Politics</a></li>
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Sciense</a></li>
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Religion</a></li>
            <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Health</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="header__burger">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My code on Codepen https://codepen.io/sennarion/pen/dyRKBxK

Comment: Please write in english

Comment: Please write your question in english [More Info](http://idownvotedbecau.se/wronglanguage)

Comment: Which language is that? The characters of it look beautiful :)

Comment: when you say: "The style and project is set" do you mean you cannot change the css and the html? Is using javascript your only option?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the css and html, you could do it like this:

first lose the javascript.
add the following to the css:

```css
.nav__item {
    position: relative;
}

.nav__item:hover > .categories__wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

then move the top property from .categories__wrapper to .categories__content and set the top on .categories__wrapper to 0

```css
.categories__wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100px;
}

.categories__content {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

and finally wrap the categories in a navigation item with class="nav__item" like this:

```html
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav__item">
      <span class="categories__link">Categories</span>
      <div class="categories__wrapper">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

```css
.header__nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
}

.nav__item {
    position: relative;
}

.nav__item:hover > .categories__wrapper {
    display: block;
}

.categories__link {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.categories__link:hover {
    color: #2F80ED;
}

.categories__wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100px;
}

.categories__content {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.categories__content::after {
    z-index: -10;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #BDBDBD;
}

.categories__content::before {
    z-index: 10;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.categories__list {
    display: flex;
    padding: 14px 30px;
}

.list__link {
    line-height: 150%;
    color: #000000;
}

.list__link:hover {
    color: #2F80ED;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__nav">
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav__item">
      <span class="categories__link">Categories</span>
      <div class="categories__wrapper">
        <div class="categories__content">
          <div class="categories__list">
            <ul class="left__list">
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Sport</a></li>
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>World</a></li>
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Covid</a></li>
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Business</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right__list">
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Politics</a></li>
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Sciense</a></li>
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Religion</a></li>
              <li><a class="list__link" href="" #>Health</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="header__burger">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```